# Problems with a PHP include from the command line (or cronjob)

Tags: linux, mysql, php, amazon-ec2, cron

I am trying to setup a cronjob on my AWS EC2 instance. There is nothing wrong with the actual entry in the crontab file but when I try to run the command in the command line I get this response.

```
PHP Warning:  include(../scripts/connect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../scripts/connect.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  include(../scripts/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../scripts/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'UTC/0.0/no DST' instead in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 6
PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 6
PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/htdocs/crons/emailnotifications.php on line 7
```

I can load this page in my browser and it works fine, but not from the command line (or cronjob).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> include(../scripts/connect.php)

Your script is using a relative directory.  These are linked to the current working directory.  When cron is running your CWD is almost certainly not what you think it is.  Either set the CWD in your cron script, or update your PHP code to use use a path relative to themselves.  Something like `include(realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../scripts/connect.php'))` perhaps?

The rest of your problems are also, almost certainly something related to the specific environment of your cron session being different from the environment when the web server runs the script.  Find the differences, and fix them.